# Animation within Container issue in Blackberry Cascade?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

While i am translating button one position to another position, the animation add within container only. Actually i need to translate the Button some inner container xy points to parent container xz points. This is my code.

```
tileAnimation[count]=ParallelAnimation::create(mPlayField[count])
                .add(TranslateTransition::create().toY(1200).duration(3000))
                .add(FadeTransition::create().to(0).duration(3000));
```

How can i do this? Its working fine in single container. If my design has container within container its making problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "add within container only" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe you can translate an object out of its parent (at least that does not make any sense to me). What you should do is have the button you want to move in the outer Container position so that is overlays the inner Container, then translate it to the location you want in the outer container.